# Getting session null in GWT application in web mode but not in hosted mode

Tags: spring, gwt, tomcat6, session-state

I am running a GWT application which maintains a user cache in session object. I am using Spring Security 3.0.5.

Following is the code I am using to get session object

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(false);
if(session != null)
     return session;
else
     throw new IllegalStateException("Session Expired");
```

In hosted mode i.e. jetty server, everything works fine and I am able to retrieve session object but in web mode i.e. tomcat 6, session object is returned null

I am using the following entries in web.xml, required to run the above code

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

**UPDATE**

Following is the spring security settings I am using

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**Phoenix.html*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.html" default-target-url="/Phoenix.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997" always-use-default-target="true"/>
    <remember-me/>
    <logout />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/login.html"/>
    <session-management><concurrency-control/></session-management>
</http>
```

**UPDATE**

This is happening because in web mode after login
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().toString()` returns "anonymousUser"
while in hosted mode the same expression returns the login credentials of the user logged in. 
Following are the urls I am using
hosted mode: http://127.0.0.1:8888/Phoenix.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

web mode: http://localhost:8185/PhoenixMCDemo/Phoenix.html;jsessionid=E56C80258410D102E6B51EFEE5AA0E91

Comment: exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you [enable sessions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions)?

Comment: I am not working in app engine mode and anyway, was able to login to create the session object initially. The problem was that rpc requests were not identified due to lack of session id in its url. I solved it by using cookies for session management. For more details refer: http://technical-ramblings.blogspot.com/2011/05/accessing-session-objects-with-gwt-and.html